# Compare register value using logical AND (&) and ==

Tags: microcontroller, c, cortex-m

```
// Hardware sets a RIS interrupt status bit    
if(GPIO_PORTE_RIS_R & 0x10)   
{
   // Software acknowledges the flag and clears the read-only RIS bit by setting ICR
   GPIO_PORTE_ICR_R = 0x10;  
   // something useful 
}
```

The above code should be self explanatory - the hardware flags a register bit, the software clears it. What I don't understand is why the code uses `GPIO_PORTE_RIS_R & 0x10` to compare register value instead of `GPIO_PORTE_RIS_R == 0x10`.

`==` operation would probably equivalent to a `CMP` followed by a `BEQ` or `BNE` in assembly, or it can be `SUBS` with a branch by flagging the `Z` (Zero) bit.  Either way using `==` is straightforward and intuitive - I don't have to convert values into binaries to predict an outcome.

But with `&` and say if `GPIO_PORTE_RIS_R = 0x20`, the <del>logical</del> bitwise AND operation between `0x20 & 0x10` or `0010.0000 & 0001.0000` in binary will result in 0000.0000 or a **false**. And imagine if `GPIO_PORTE_RIS_R = 0x30` or `0011.0000` in binary, the condition statement would return  **true** even if the two operands (`0x30 & 0x10`) don't equate. It seems as if the `&` operator checks if a register *contains* a value (or vice versa, a register is subset of a value). It's just confusing to think or use.

In what situation should I use `&` instead of `==` and why? And is there a simpler way to think about it?

Comment: One more thing: in C, logical AND is `&&` and bitwise AND is `&`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you write `if REG & 0x10` you're checking whether bit 4 of the register `REG` is set.

If the value of REG is 0x30, then bit 4 is set, and you should do the thing you want to do when bit 4 is set.

If the value of the REG is 0x20 then bit 4 isn't set, so you shouldn't do the thing you want to do when bit 4 is set.

And that's exactly the behavior you get if you write `if REG & 0x10 {...}`.

> What I don't understand is why the code uses `GPIO_PORTE_RIS_R & 0x10` to compare register value instead of `GPIO_PORTE_RIS_R == 0x10`.

If you used `==` then if bit 4 was set, but some other bit was also set, then you wouldn't do whatever it is you want to do when bit 4 is set.

But since you want to do that thing when bit 4 is set regardless of what other bits are set, then this is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Rule of thumb:

- Use `&` when you care about individual bits and only those bits.
- Use `==` when you care about the whole value of a variable.

You can of course also use `&` to check a whole variable against a mask, and in that case it is almost equivalent to `==`. Except `&` returns either zero or a non-zero value, while `==` always returns either `0` or `1`.

---

Advanced differences:
Both operators are equivalent when it comes to order of evaluation - it is unspecified. They are equivalent when it comes to implicit type promotions, except the result of `&` is always of the type of the (promoted) operands, while the result of `==` is always `int`.

Example (32 bit computer):

```
uint64_t a;
uint64_t b;
printf("%zu\n", sizeof (a & b));  // prints 8
printf("%zu\n", sizeof (a == b)); // prints 4
```

Comment: For C++ users: `==` returns a `bool`.